# Count Emails by month of a year

Tags: vba, excel, outlook

I modified my search email code to count.

```
Public Sub mycounter()
Dim outlookapp
Dim olns As Outlook.Namespace
Dim Fldr As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim olMail As Object
'Dim olMail As Outlook.MailItem
Dim myTasks
Dim projIDsearch As String
Dim myrecipient As Outlook.Recipient
Dim daysAgo As Long
Dim strfilter As String
Dim emailcount As Integer

Set outlookapp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set olns = outlookapp.GetNamespace("MAPI")

Set myrecipient = olns.CreateRecipient("SharedMailbox")
myrecipient.Resolve
Set Fldr = olns.GetSharedDefaultFolder(myrecipient, olFolderInbox)

daysAgo = CInt(ProjIDSearcher.ComboBox1.Text)

Set myTasks = Fldr.Items
Set myTasks = myTasks.Restrict("[ReceivedTime]>'" & Format(Date - daysAgo, "DDDDD HH:NN") & "'")

For Each olMail In myTasks
    emailcount = emailcount + 1
    'Exit For
Next

MsgBox "here it is:" & emailcount

End Sub
```

This code counts by days back. Is there a way I can throw a specific date from a dropdown to this?

```
Set myTasks = myTasks.Restrict("[ReceivedTime]>'" & Format(Date - daysAgo, "DDDDD HH:NN") & "'")
```

Right now, daysAgo is taking number values from a drop down. I need to count emails for a specific month/year so I can count the number of emails received in let's say January 2017 or May 2016.

Comment: This one requires you to have your list of dates that you want to check for in column A, with no blank cells between them.  it's fairly fast.  https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/377786-excel-outlook-vba-macro-to-count-emails-per-day

Comment: hi. thank you for the reply. i've checked the link but i don't think it fits my requirement. i need to be able to count at least per month not per date/row.

Comment: The array in that example also has the "Month(.ReceivedTime)" in it, so you can alter the code to count for month instead of just each day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot test your code, but the construction of the filter to allow for retrieval of items in a given date range can look like:

```
sFilter = ""
sFilter = "[ReceivedTime] >= '" & Format(StartDate, "ddddd h:nn AMPM") & "'"
sFilter = sFilter & " AND [ReceivedTime] <= '" & Format(EndDate, "ddddd h:nn AMPM") & "'"
```

The rules for construction of the filter can be found in the MSDN knowledge base under the `Items.Restrict(filter)` discussion.

In the above, note that EndDate would logically need to be the day after the desired ending date, assuming you want the count to include EndDate (or you could do EndDate +1 and a `<` operator).